# Rails order by sum of two association's columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :question_articles
  has_many :articles, through: :question_articles
end
```

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :question_articles
  has_many :questions, through: :question_articles
end
```

```
class QuestionArticle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :question
end
```

`question_articles` table contains 2 columns: `user_usages_count` and `admin_usages_count`.

I need to retrieve `questions` ordered by `question_articles.user_usages_count` + `question_articles.admin_usages_count`

I've tried:

```
Question  
  .joins(:articles)
  .includes(:question_articles)
  .order('question_articles.admin_usages_count + question_articles.user_usages_count DESC')
```

but I am getting `'disallow_raw_sql!': Query method called with non-attribute argument`

Comment: What is your actual problem? Is there an unexpected result or an error? How does the error message look like?

Answer (score 2):

to fix the issue with `'disallow_raw_sql!': Query method called with non-attribute argument` we need to use build in `Arel.sql` method

So the working solution would be

```
Question  
  .joins(:articles)
  .includes(:question_articles)
  .order(Arel.sql('question_articles.admin_usages_count + question_articles.user_usages_count DESC'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to avoid referring to SQL at all and keep your logic in ruby by creating a method in your Question model that looks something like this (assuming that you need the total of those two fields from all related `QuestionArticle` records).

```rb
def self.by_usage
  all.sort_by do |_question|
    _question.question_articles.reduce(0) { |_sum, _qa| _sum += (_qa.user_usages_count + _qa.admin_usages_count) }
  end
end
```

You should then be able to use `@questions.by_usage` and get back the Question records sorted by the total of all usage numbers in the related QuestionArticle records for each Question.

Assuming this does what you need, you could neaten it up further by adding a method to the QuestionArticles model that returns the total of these two fields:

```rb
def total_usage
  user_usages_count + admin_usages_count
end
```

The `reduce` line would then simplify to:

```rb
_question.question_articles.reduce(0) { |_sum, _qa| _sum += _qa.total_usage }
```

Which itself simplifies to:

```rb
_question.question_articles.reduce(&:total_usage)
```